# What is known about these "Captain Raygun" characters?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, marvel, x-men-2

In X-Men 2 you see in a very short scene the name of a jet-pilot, CAPT. RAYGUN MacLAI.

[image]

I googled a bit, but only found a name from battlestar galactica which sounds similar, [Captain Raymond "Raygun" Lai](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Raymond_Lai), but this is from 2008, so newer than the movie.

[image]

So my question (in two parts)

**Is this just a generic name for the movie, or is this a known character from the X-Men or Marvel-universe? If so, can you provide some information about this character?**

**Is there a connection between the Battlestar Character and the X-Men character?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Ray "Raygun" Lai](http://www.raygun.ca/) is a professional comic-book artist and movie concept artist. He worked on both the [Battlestar Galactica Miniseries](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0481719/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr162) (as a "Series Illustrator") as well as the [X-Men 2 film](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0481719/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr162) (as a "Graphic Designer").

The BSG Wiki mentions that his name was included as a thank-you for his work.

> Ray Lai was a concept artist for the 2003 Miniseries. His name appears
>   in the show as an honorific.

And you may wish to note the web address for his personal website; [www.**raygun**.ca](http://www.raygun.ca/)

---

**It seems likely that his name is the inspiration for both *Captain Raymond "Raygun" Lai* and *Captain "Raygun" MacLAI.***

Comment: For the record, this character only merits a passing mention in the novel, and not by name; *"The Blackbird shuddered in wake turbulence as the Falcons shot past to announce their presence, then throttled back to pace the bigger aircraft, taking up flanking positions on either side. Each of the pilots was making a downward gesture, telling them to land at once.*"

Comment: Great answer and good research, but only one small point: You wrote `...inspiration for .... and Ray "Raygun" MacLai`. Afaik the character in X-Men 2 is only introduced by the letters on the jet, and also it seems to be female, so I guess we dont know her firstname, we only know it is an Captain.

Comment: @kl78 - You're not wrong. Edited accordingly. For the record, we also never see Raymond Lai in BSG. For all we know, she could just have a very manly name.